# JDT source formmatter: a method is skipped and is not properly formatted

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I have a `SourceFormatter` class that should format the provided source code and replace all tabs with spaces and put braces on a new line:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ISourceRange;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatterConstants;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;

public class SourceFormatter
{

    private static final IProgressMonitor PROGRESS_MONITOR = new NullProgressMonitor();


    public void formatCompilationUnitSource(final ICompilationUnit compilationUnit) throws JavaModelException
    {
        final Hashtable<String, String> options = JavaCore.getDefaultOptions();
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_TAB_CHAR, JavaCore.SPACE);
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_BRACE_POSITION_FOR_METHOD_DECLARATION,
                    DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.NEXT_LINE);
        final CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options, ToolFactory.M_FORMAT_EXISTING);
        final ISourceRange range = compilationUnit.getSourceRange();
        final TextEdit formatEdit = formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT,
                                                     compilationUnit.getSource(),
                                                     range.getOffset(),
                                                     range.getLength(),
                                                     0,
                                                     null);
        if (formatEdit != null && formatEdit.hasChildren())
        {
            compilationUnit.applyTextEdit(formatEdit, PROGRESS_MONITOR);
        }
        compilationUnit.save(PROGRESS_MONITOR, true);
    }

}
```

The problem is that not every tab is replaced with spaces and not every brace is put on a new line. The following test highlights the issue. See the `body()` method..

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragmentRoot;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall;
import org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime;
import org.eclipse.jdt.launching.LibraryLocation;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import my.project.SourceFormatter;

public class SourceFormatterTest
{

    private static final String TEST_PRJ_PKG_NAME = "test.project";

    private static final NullProgressMonitor PROGRESS_MONITOR = new NullProgressMonitor();

    private IProject testProject;

    private IJavaProject testJavaProject;

    private IPackageFragment testPackage;

    private File javaFile;

    private SourceFormatter sourceFormatter;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception
    {
        final IWorkspaceRoot wksRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

        testProject = wksRoot.getProject(TEST_PRJ_PKG_NAME);
        testProject.create(PROGRESS_MONITOR);
        testProject.open(PROGRESS_MONITOR);

        final IProjectDescription description = testProject.getDescription();
        description.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID });
        testProject.setDescription(description, null);

        this.testJavaProject = JavaCore.create(testProject);
        this.testJavaProject.open(PROGRESS_MONITOR);

        final IFolder binFolder = testProject.getFolder("bin");
        if (!binFolder.exists())
        {
            binFolder.create(false, true, null);
        }
        this.testJavaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);

        final List<IClasspathEntry> entries = new ArrayList<IClasspathEntry>();
        final IVMInstall vmInstall = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall();
        final LibraryLocation[] locations = JavaRuntime.getLibraryLocations(vmInstall);
        for (final LibraryLocation element : locations)
        {
            entries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(element.getSystemLibraryPath(), null, null));
        }
        // add libs to project class path
        this.testJavaProject.setRawClasspath(entries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[entries.size()]), null);

        final IFolder sourceFolder = testProject.getFolder("src");
        sourceFolder.create(false, true, null);

        final IPackageFragmentRoot root = this.testJavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder);
        final IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = this.testJavaProject.getRawClasspath();
        final IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
        newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(root.getPath());
        this.testJavaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);

        this.testPackage = this.testJavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder)
                .createPackageFragment(TEST_PRJ_PKG_NAME, false, null);

        File packageDirectory = this.testPackage.getResource().getRawLocation().toFile();
        final File javaFile = new File(packageDirectory, "Test.java");

        this.javaFile = new File(javaFile.getAbsolutePath());

        this.sourceFormatter = new SourceFormatter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFormatCompilationUnitSource() throws Exception
    {
        // Prepare file
        final List<String> lines = Lists.newArrayList("package " + this.testPackage.getElementName() + ";",
                                                      "",
                                                      "import test.project.Procedure;",
                                                      "import test.project.ConfirmationStatus;",
                                                      "",
                                                      "public class Test {",
                                                      "",
                                                      "    public void body(){", //This method isn't formatted as expected
                                                      "        step(\"step1\", this::step1);",
                                                      "\u0009\u0009step(\"step2\", this::step2);",
                                                      "    }",
                                                      "",
                                                      "    public ConfirmationStatus step1(){",
                                                      "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                                                      "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                                                      "    }",
                                                      "",
                                                      "    public ConfirmationStatus step2()",
                                                      "    {",
                                                      "\u0009\u0009//this is some previous content to preserve",
                                                      "\u0009\u0009return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                                                      "    }",
                                                      "",
                                                      "}",
                                                      "",
                                                      "");
        String sources = Joiner.on("\n").join(lines);
        ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = this.testPackage
                .createCompilationUnit("TestProcedure.java", sources, false, PROGRESS_MONITOR);
        compilationUnit.open(PROGRESS_MONITOR);

        // Run test
        this.sourceFormatter.formatCompilationUnitSource(compilationUnit);

        // Asserts

        final List<String> expectedLines = Lists.newArrayList("package " + this.testPackage.getElementName() + ";",
                                                              "",
                                                              "import test.project.Procedure;",
                                                              "import test.project.ConfirmationStatus;",
                                                              "",
                                                              "public class TestProcedure extends Procedure {",
                                                              "",
                                                              "    public void body()",
                                                              "    {",
                                                              "        step(\"step1\", this::step1);",
                                                              "        step(\"step2\", this::step2);",
                                                              "    }",
                                                              "",
                                                              "    public ConfirmationStatus step1()",
                                                              "    {",
                                                              "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                                                              "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                                                              "    }",
                                                              "",
                                                              "    public ConfirmationStatus step2()",
                                                              "    {",
                                                              "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                                                              "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                                                              "    }",
                                                              "",
                                                              "}",
                                                              "");

        final String expectedFileContents = Joiner.on("\n").join(expectedLines);
        final String actualFileContents = Files.toString(this.javaFile, Charsets.UTF_8);

        assertEquals(expectedFileContents, actualFileContents);

    }

}
```

What am I missing? Why the `body()` method is not formatted? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...
This test should be ready to be runned as a JUnit Plugin Test.

Comment: You could simplify your test by just using:
String source = "...";
IDocument doc = new Document(source);
TextEdit edit = formatter.format(kind, doc.get(), 0, doc.get().length(), 0, null);

Comment: Are the values for range.getOffset() and range.getLength() ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `JavaCore.getDefaultOptions()` the formatting is as expected.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatterConstants;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CodeFormatterTest {

    private CodeFormatter codeFormatter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, "1.8");
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, "1.8");
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, "1.8");
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_TAB_CHAR, JavaCore.SPACE);
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_BRACE_POSITION_FOR_METHOD_DECLARATION,
            DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.NEXT_LINE);

        codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCanFormat() {
        final List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("package test;",
                "",
                "import test.project.Procedure;",
                "import test.project.ConfirmationStatus;",
                "",
                "public class TestProcedure extends Procedure {", // FIXED
                "",
                "    public void body(){",
                "        step(\"step1\", this::step1);",
                "\u0009\u0009step(\"step2\", this::step2);",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    public ConfirmationStatus step1(){",
                "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    public ConfirmationStatus step2()",
                "    {",
                "\u0009\u0009//this is some previous content to preserve",
                "\u0009\u0009return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                "    }",
                "",
                "}",
                "",
                "");
        String originSource = lines
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(String.format("%n")));

        String formattedSource = format(originSource, CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

        final List<String> expectedLines = Arrays.asList("package test;",
                "",
                "import test.project.Procedure;",
                "import test.project.ConfirmationStatus;",
                "",
                "public class TestProcedure extends Procedure {",
                "",
                "    public void body()",
                "    {",
                "        step(\"step1\", this::step1);",
                "        step(\"step2\", this::step2);",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    public ConfirmationStatus step1()",
                "    {",
                "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    public ConfirmationStatus step2()",
                "    {",
                "        //this is some previous content to preserve",
                "        return ConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED;",
                "    }",
                "",
                "}",
                "");
        String expectedFormattedSource = expectedLines
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(String.format("%n")));

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedFormattedSource, formattedSource);
    }

    public String format(String source, int kind) {
        IDocument doc = new Document(source);
        TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(kind, doc.get(), 0,
                doc.get().length(), 0, null);
        if (edit != null) {
            try {
                edit.apply(doc);
                source = doc.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

}
```